# How do I create a session to use my profile?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk

#### Version of AWS SDK for Go?

```
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.28.9
```

#### Version of Go (`go version`)?

```
> go version                                                                                                                                                                                              master [c6a9853] modified untracked
go version go1.13.6 darwin/amd64
```

#### What issue did you see?

Creating a session doesn't pick up the specified profile.

I set the following environment variables:

```
AWS_CONFIG_FILE=~/.aws/config
AWS_CREDENTIALS_FILE=~/.aws/credentials
AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=~/.aws/credentials
AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
```

And I create the session like this:

```
sess, err := session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
  Profile: "dev",

  Config: aws.Config{
    Region:                        aws.String("us-west-2"),
    CredentialsChainVerboseErrors: aws.Bool(true),
  },

  SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
})

if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

ssmsvc := ssm.New(sess)
keyname := "/dev/ops/test/slack/api_token"
withDecryption := false
param, err := ssmsvc.GetParameter(&ssm.GetParameterInput{
  Name:           &keyname,
  WithDecryption: &withDecryption,
})

if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}

value := *param.Parameter.Value
fmt.Println(value)
```

And I get this as a result:

```
panic: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain
caused by: EnvAccessKeyNotFound: failed to find credentials in the environment.
SharedCredsLoad: failed to load profile, dev.
EC2RoleRequestError: no EC2 instance role found
caused by: RequestError: send request failed
```

However, AWS CLI can pick up my profile easily:

```
>aws ssm get-parameter --region="us-west-2" --profile="dev" --name="/dev/ops/test/slack/api_token"
{
    "Parameter": {
        "Name": "/dev/ops/test/slack/api_token",
        "Type": "SecureString",
        "Value": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==",
        "Version": 1,
        "LastModifiedDate": 1580165013.606,
        "ARN": "arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:parameter/dev/ops/test/slack/api_token"
    }
}
```

More reference (my dev profile as well as my bridge profile):

```
> cat ~/.aws/config                                                                                                                                                                                       master [c6a9853] modified untracked
[profile dev]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/admin
role_session_name = name
source_profile = bridge
region = us-west-2
```

```
> cat ~/.aws/credentials                                                                                                                                                                                  master [c6a9853] modified untracked
[bridge]
aws_access_key_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

#### Steps to reproduce

Configure a session to use a role from the `~/.aws/config` file.

Comment: I _suspect_ that the ability to specify a role in the `.aws/config` file is a feature of the AWS CLI rather than the SDK. Therefore, you will need to use the `bridge` profile to obtain credentials, then call `AssumeRole()` to use the IAM Role. If that fails, try putting the credentials in a `[default]` profile and do not specify a `Profile:` (just as a test).

Answer (score 1):

Fixed: needed to use the absolute path for the environment variables pointing to the `.aws` files.